# mbed dc motor speed control using optocoupler encoder

Tags: control, motor

i have been playing with mbed since few week ago and would like to create a test program for dcmotor speed control. im using a 24V dc motor with encoder attach.. then test,
at first i test with supplying a 5v and 3.3V from mbed to the motor. the thing work fine giving a 16 and 10rpm respectively.
later i try using 12v it give 40rpm. 
then i try a 24v input, now the speed wont come out. and also the counter that count each on/off tick not counting up.

any possible reason?
my though that maybe when it move so fast that the ISR routine couldn't catch up to the speed..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a schematic and part numbers? Are you passing 24V to just the motor or to the motor AND encoder?  What is the rated voltage on both?

Comment: hi its a Sankyo JHAOB15 motor and mbed lpc1768. i try to upload circuit together in above but it seems i cant upload new picture due to not enough 'reputation'.

Comment: im not sure about about the encoder. but the motor use 24V if not mistaken. i salvaged this motor from work and cant find any data on this..

Comment: I agree - I looked around briefly online and couldn't find any specification or a datasheet for the motor. The thing you salvaged it from - was it working?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's not clear what components you have and thus not really possible to help troubleshoot. I can't find datasheets for your equipment. If you can post a link to one I'll retract my vote.

Comment: yes its working, i got from atm machine card reader. well, i'm pretty much confuse myself, there are few places that sell this motor but not a single one have a datasheet.sure, no point it being here if no one can help.. thanks anyway for your effort

Comment: Why did you post a screenshot of your code instead of just copy-pasting the code?